# Power/sample size estimation when comparing two AUCs (area under the curve)?

Tags: r, sample-size, statistical-power, roc, auc

Are there any R functions (or other free software) for calculating power/sample size needed to compare 2 AUCs (area under the curve)?

Specifically, suppose you want to fit 2 different models to a dataset to predict a binary outcome, and you want to test whether the AUCs from these 2 models differ.  Given that the 2 AUCs are calculated on the same dataset, they are technically correlated/paired.

I found a few paid-options, but I'm hoping to find free R code for doing the same power calculation:

- https://www.ncss.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_Two_ROC_Curves.pdf
- https://www.medcalc.org/manual/sample-size-ROC-comparison.php

Lastly, the [pROC R package](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/pROC/html/power.roc.test.html) implements one approach, however, it requires having preliminary data for both ROC curves (which I don't have).  So I'm trying to find a method that implements the analytic power calculations, similar to the 2 paid options above.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. What do you want to do exactly? Power or sample size? What info do you have on the curves?
You will need to have at least some basic idea of your data if you want to compute anything...